# Body is rendering before the header in Layout page in next 13

Tags: next.js, layout, rendering

Just runnig the things with usual flow until this happened
but if i exclude the body from layout and other pages stays there then things work smooth
but when body is there it is being shown on the top of a page even before the header which is called before the body

This is the layout.tsx code file

```
import './globals.css'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import Header from '@/components/layout/header'
import Footer from '@/components/layout/footer'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Panawerse Dao Next 13',
  description: 'Generated by Saleh',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Header />
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      <Footer/>
    </html>
  )
}
```

this is what i tried
on the screeen top most thing is body components then header and then footer
i dont know where the problem is generating from

Answer (score 0):

Change your RootLayout to return something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <Header />
    {children}
    <Footer/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note how `Header` and `Footer` surround `children`, but are still part of the `body` tag.